# IN clause with spring boot specification for list of string

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table `Media` that has a column "tagList" that contains the list of string. I m trying to write the specification for search query.

Below specification is working fine if `inputTag` is `mentos` and tagList is ["mentos","bollywood","cinema"] but if inputTag is "men" it is not returning any row. How to replace the isMember with in so that it matches for substring as well.

This is the code:

```
public class MediaRepositoryService {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
private MediaRepository mediaRepo;

@Transactional
public List<Media> searchMedia(final String inputTag) {
    List<Media> cases = mediaRepo.findAll(MediaSearchSpecificaton.findByCriteria(inputTag));
    return cases;
}

private static class MediaSearchSpecificaton {

    private static Specification<Media> findByCriteria(String inputTag) {

        return new Specification<Media>() {
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Media> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

                Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
                predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate, criteriaBuilder.isMember(inputTag, root.get("tagList")));

                return predicate;
            }
        };
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JPA's Repository Like query method` like:

Add this method in `MediaRepository`

```
List<Media> findByTagListContaining(String inputTag);
```

and then call it from your method like

```
List<Media> cases = mediaRepo.findByTagListContaining(inputTag);
```

Comment: Actually later inputTag will be List<String>,This is the reason I m using specification.

Comment: @Aashish `List<Media> findByTagListIn(List<String> inputTags)`